# Is there a way to use an active Bootstrap element as an input to a Django form?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I want to use a Bootstrap list group as seen [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior) as a choice selection tool in a form.

One of the list items in the said Bootstrap list can have an `active` attribute at a time. I was hoping to *map* that `active` attribute to a choice in a Django `forms.ChoiceField`, thus making the list into a radio button of sorts.

The current state of my code:

views.py

```
def some_form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = SomeForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'myapp/form_template.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    choices = [("Foo", "Foo"),("Bar", "Bar")]
    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

template

```
<!-- Load bootstrap, meta-tags, etc. -->
<form action="some_action" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Load the choice field -->
        {{ form.choices_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- The list thingy I got from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <!-- List of items that I want to be selectable as choices -->
            <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Foo</a>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Bar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <!-- Dynamically appearing descriptions of items that I want to be selectable as choices -->
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">Foo</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">Bar</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried so far? This would likely require some JavaScript to perform the mapping and post the data to the server.

Comment: @AlexHart I have written the form fields (by subclassing Djangos's `forms.ModelForms`), a View and a template to render that view. Would it help if I were to prepare representative code snippets?

Comment: Absolutely, code generally gives people context and you'll generally get a lot more responses.

Comment: @AlexHart Got it. I've added the code snippets.